# Do Options take Dividend into account?

Tags: india, options, stock-markets, dividends

Suppose I own a contract with a market lot of 100 shares in company A and company A goes ex-dividend during the validity of the contract.  That means, that theoretically  the price of company A will fall by the dividend amount on the ex-dividend date. How will that be taken into account when pricing the option? Or, is that ignored completely?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No can't make quick bucks. It depends very much on what the strike price was.

> Dividends which are below 10% of the market value of the underlying
>   stock, would be deemed to be ordinary dividends and no adjustment in
>   the Strike Price would be made for ordinary dividends. For
>   extra-ordinary dividends, above 10% of the market value of the
>   underlying security, the Strike Price would be adjusted.

Refer more at [NSE India](http://www.nseindia.com/products/content/derivatives/equities/corporate_adjustment.htm)

**Edit:**
The Nifty consists of [50 stocks](http://www.motilaloswal.com/Broking/Markets/Index-Weightage). The largest one has weight of around 8%. So 10% on this will only translate to .8% on index.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot. That helped. Do you happen to know about index options? Say a stock with a lot of weight-age on the index( such as INFY) declares a dividend of more than 10%. How would that be adjusted in the Strike Price of the underlying index option.

Comment: +1 - once again, thanks for being our guy in India. I missed the tag, and was answering USian.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer No thanks needed, I am here because I like it :). In this case I guess the practises are similar. You answer is also same as mine and equally valid.

Answer (score 3):

The CBOE had a great article on this. I will search for it and edit.

The normal dividends are not adjusted. Which is why you see early exercise of just out of the money options sometimes. To get that dividend.

A special dividend, say a $50 stock with $1/yr dividend but now has a $3 one time dividend would likely result in an option strike adjustment.

Comment: Would it be possible to use this to my advantage? Lets say I know when a company is going ex-dividend. Can I write a call, knowing that the price is likely to fall on ex-dividend date? Or would the dividend be deducted from my margin?

Comment: The amount of the dividend arbitrage will be reflected in the price of the option.

Answer (score 0):

Both of the answers that you received missed the point of your question.

Yes, the terms of an option contract are adjusted when there is a special dividend that exceeds 10%  of the market value of the underlying but those are infrequent occurrences.

Pending dividends prior to expiration affect options, increasing put premium and decreasing call premium.

Answer (score -1):

Options are the quasi-futures.
Futures are following the price moves caused by new information.

Will the price follow the new information? Yes.

Will the price follow the old information? No. Because it is already in-the-price.